# How to set a minimum column height or range so that values in a stackedcolumn do not overlap?

Tags: highcharts, height, stacked

my problem is when the column value is really small, the number text  overlaps with the number in the next column. How do I set a minium column height or range to avoid this layout problem? Thanks. Here's  a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/q46WQ/4/

```
          $(function () {

        var categoryImgs = {
            'Banana': '<img src="/images/2.png"><img>&nbsp;',
            'Orange': '<img src="/images/8.png"><img>&nbsp;',
            'Fruit': '<img src="/images/12.png"><img>&nbsp;',
            'Apple': '<img src="/images/4.png"><img>&nbsp;',
            'Coconut': '<img src="/images/3.png"><img>&nbsp;'
        };

        var totals = new Array();
        var stackTotals = new Array();
        var i = 5, j = 0;
        //totals = HighchartsAdapter
        function reverse() {
            totals.reverse();
        }

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Premium Summary'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Banana', 'Fruit', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Coconut'],
                labels: {
                    x: 5,
                    useHTML: true,

                    formatter: function () {

                        var n = totals.shift();
                        return '<div class="stacktotal">$' + n + '</div><div id="div1" class="myToolTip' + this.value + '">' + categoryImgs[this.value] + '</div>';
                    },
                    events: {
                        mouseover: function (e) {
                            var elm = e.currentTarget.children.div1.className;

                            switch (elm) {
                                case "myToolTipBanana":
                                    document.getElementById('hoverboard').style.display = "block";
                                    $('#hoverboard').html('<img style="padding-left:7px; padding-bottom: 30px" src="/images/2.png"><img>&nbsp;<div class="desc">39 year old female non smoker - Occupation Class 1</div><table>' +
                                        '<tr><td><b>Jam</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>$80,000</td><td class="pad">$89</td></tr>' +
                                        '<tr><td><b>Fruit</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>-</td><td class="pad">$150</td></tr>' +
                                        '<tr><td><b>Candy</b></td><td>Nil Excess</td><td class="pad">$150</td></tr>' +
                                        '<tr><td colspan="3" class="pad" ><hr /></td></tr><tr><td><span id="policy">Boxes</span></td><td></td><td class="pad">$200.12</td></tr>' +
                                        '<tr bgcolor="#EDF7F7"><td style="font-size:14px;"><b>Total Premium (Monthly)</b></td><td></td><td class="pad"><b>$514.55<b></td></tr>' + '</table>');
                                    break;
                                case "myToolTipFruit":
                                    document.getElementById('hoverboard').style.display = "block";
                                    $('#hoverboard').html('<img style="padding-left:7px; padding-bottom: 30px" src="/images/8.png"><img>&nbsp;<div class="desc">39 year old female non smoker - Occupation Class 1</div><table>' +
                                       '<tr><td><b>Jam</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>$80,000</td><td class="pad">$400</td></tr>' +
                                       '<tr><td><b>Fruit</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>-</td><td class="pad">$186.76</td></tr>' +
                                       '<tr><td><b>Candy</b></td><td>Nil Excess</td><td class="pad">$210.23</td></tr>' +
                                       '<tr><td colspan="3" class="pad" ><hr /></td></tr><tr><td><span id="policy">Boxes</span></td><td></td><td class="pad">$290</td></tr>' +
                                       '<tr bgcolor="#EDF7F7"><td style="font-size:14px;"><b>Total Premium (Monthly)</b></td><td></td><td class="pad"><b>$1086.99<b></td></tr>' + '</table>');
                                    break;
                                case "myToolTipOrange":
                                    document.getElementById('hoverboard').style.display = "block";
                                    $('#hoverboard').html('<img style="padding-left:7px; padding-bottom: 30px" src="/images/12.png"><img>&nbsp;<div class="desc">39 year old female non smoker - Occupation Class 1</div><table>' +
                                      '<tr><td><b>Jam</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>$80,000</td><td class="pad">$258.13</td></tr>' +
                                      '<tr><td><b>Fruit</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>-</td><td class="pad">$150</td></tr>' +
                                      '<tr><td><b>Candy</b></td><td>Nil Excess</td><td class="pad">$143.50</td></tr>' +
                                      '<tr><td colspan="3" class="pad" ><hr /></td></tr><tr><td><span id="policy">Boxes</span></td><td></td><td class="pad">$45.78</td></tr>' +
                                      '<tr bgcolor="#EDF7F7"><td style="font-size:14px;"><b>Total Premium (Monthly)</b></td><td></td><td class="pad"><b>$597.41<b></td></tr>' + '</table>');
                                    break;
                                case "myToolTipApple":
                                    document.getElementById('hoverboard').style.display = "block";
                                    $('#hoverboard').html('<img style="padding-left:7px; padding-bottom: 30px" src="/images/3.png"><img>&nbsp;<div class="desc">39 year old female non smoker - Occupation Class 1</div><table>' +
                                      '<tr><td><b>Jam</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>$80,000</td><td class="pad">$212</td></tr>' +
                                      '<tr><td><b>Fruit</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>-</td><td class="pad">$200</td></tr>' +
                                      '<tr><td><b>Candy</b></td><td>Nil Excess</td><td class="pad">$219</td></tr>' +
                                      '<tr><td colspan="3" class="pad" ><hr /></td></tr><tr><td><span id="policy">Boxes</span></td><td></td><td class="pad">$71</td></tr>' +
                                      '<tr bgcolor="#EDF7F7"><td style="font-size:14px;"><b>Total Premium (Monthly)</b></td><td></td><td class="pad"><b>$702<b></td></tr>' + '</table>');
                                    break;
                                case "myToolTipCoconut":
                                    document.getElementById('hoverboard').style.display = "block";
                                    $('#hoverboard').html('<img style="padding-left:7px; padding-bottom: 30px" src="/images/4.png"><img>&nbsp;<div class="desc">39 year old female non smoker - Occupation Class 1</div><table>' +
                                      '<tr><td><b>Jam</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>$80,000</td><td class="pad">$152</td></tr>' +
                                      '<tr><td><b>Fruit</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>-</td><td class="pad">$100</td></tr>' +
                                      '<tr><td><b>Candy</b></td><td>Nil Excess</td><td class="pad">$143</td></tr>' +
                                      '<tr><td colspan="3" class="pad" ><hr /></td></tr><tr><td><span id="policy">Boxes</span></td><td></td><td class="pad">$120</td></tr>' +
                                      '<tr bgcolor="#EDF7F7"><td style="font-size:14px;"><b>Total Premium (Monthly)</b></td><td></td><td class="pad"><b>$515<b></td></tr>' + '</table>');
                                    break;
                            }
                        },
                        mouseout: function () {
                            document.getElementById('hoverboard').style.display = "none";
                            $('#hoverboard').html('');
                        }
                    },
                }
            },

            linkedTo: 0,
            categories: ['Banana', 'Fruit', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Coconut'],

            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '$' + this.value;
                    }
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black',
                    },
                    formatter: function () {
                        totals[i++] = this.total;
                        return '';
                    },

                }                    
            },

            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -70,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 20,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.series.name + ', ' + this.x  + ', ' +' $'+ this.y + '<br/>';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    borderWidth:0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'black',
                        style: {

                        },
                        format: '${y}'
                    }                        
                }

            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Jam',
                y:'$' + this.value,
                data: [200.12, 290, 45.78, 71, 120],
                color: '#B9B6BA',
            }, {
                name: 'Fruit',
                data: [150, 186.76, 150, 20, 10.0],
                color: '#E5764C'
            }, {
                name: 'Candy',
                data: [29,4, null , 21.2, 15.2],
                color: '#9D8365'
            }, {
                name: 'Boxes',
                data: [15.43, 10.23, 14.50, 21.9, 14.3],
                color: '#9F7AC3'
            } ]

        });           

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the formatter and drop the format property on to achieve this.

```
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'black',
                    style: {

                    },
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y > 30 ? "$" + this.y : null;
                    }
                }
```

Change the 30 value according to your needs. See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q46WQ/5/

Comment: do you mean change the font size if data is small? I'm not sure if it will help, is there a way to control the height of the column which is what I need though? thanks

Comment: No, the solution I provided hides the label if the value is too small. If you want to have higher columns, I guess you'll have to set a height for the chart so that it is higher than the default value. I think you can also set it via CSS on the container's height. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/q46WQ/6/ .You have stacks with small values though, so there's still a bit of overlap.